# How to create 1280x720 music video with static pic

Tags: conversion, encoding, youtube, video-editing

I wanna upload a song to youtube, and put a static 1280x720 pic as the video. I'd like the format to be one of the [recommended ones](http://www.google.com/support/youtube/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=132460).

I tried Windows Movie Maker 2.6 but it only generated a 640x480 video.
I also tried Windows Live Movie Maker but it put a big black margin around my pic (and unexplicably, produced a video with a slightly lower volume).

Do you know any way to do what I need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is info, tutorial and scripts to help you do this here:

http://tranceluvers.com/forum/index.php?showtopic=932&st=0